# cypher query to match all nodes of a specific relationship type to a specific node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have `Author` and `Articles` nodes.

`Author` has a `WROTE` relationship that links it to articles.

I would like to get all articles that have been written by an author with a specific uuid.

```
MATCH (n:Author {uuid: '8f47fb1d-2a3f-46a8-b0fc-06b24169ac86'})<-[:WROTE]-(Article)
RETURN Article
```

is what I am trying, but it is coming back with `(no changes, no records)`.

Comment: 1. If `Article` is a node label use `(a:Article)`, like you used `(n:Author)` and then return `a` not `Article`. 2. Are you sure that `WROTE` is pointing the `Author`? I would expect  `WROTE` to point the `Article` and if the relationship is pointing at the `Author` it may be called `WRITTEN_BY`...If these are not working, please provide sample data...

Comment: There is no `WRITTEN_BY` relationship type. `MATCH (ar:Article)<-[:WROTE]-(au:Author {uuid: '8f47fb1d-2a3f-46a8-b0fc-06b24169ac86'})
RETURN ar` does, however, return all the articles that I am looking for.

Articles do have a `authorUUID` property, so I've tried: `MATCH (n:Article {authorUUID: '8f47fb1d-2a3f-46a8-b0fc-06b24169ac86'}) RETURN n`

This just spins endlessly.

Comment: Your query is directed to author, it should be directed to article i.e. (author)->(article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but the direction of your relationship seems off. You also want to provide the type (i.e. "label") of your article node:

```
MATCH (n:Author {uuid: '8f47fb1d-2a3f-46a8-b0fc-06b24169ac86'})-[:WROTE]->(a:Article)
RETURN a
```

For exploring your data and if you do not know the direction, you can match relationships while ignoring the direction:

```
MATCH (n:Author {uuid: '8f47fb1d-2a3f-46a8-b0fc-06b24169ac86'})-[:WROTE]-(a:Article)
RETURN a
```